# How to make background image responsive for mobile devices

Tags: css, html

I am making a site using HTML and CSS but my background image is not responsive
for small devices like mobile its not resizing as I decrease the size of windows 
my CSS code for the image is like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border-image-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Use `background-size:contain;`

Comment: did not work bro just make website very small even in big screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using `media queries`, they are used in css to define certain screen sizes.
I recommend having a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

I would also recommend for images to have them in multiple sizes, you don't want to squash a large image onto a mobile size canvas, you should separate them into mobile/tablet/desktop

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
/* For mobile phones: */
    body {
        background-image: url(mobile_image.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        border-image-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same image to scale based on the size of the browser window:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

/*  it is used when the browser or screen size is below 767px */

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body{
            background: url(image.jpg)no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center; 
        }
    }
```